# Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue,compareTo)

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, task-parallel-library

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _1._41_Compare_and_Exchange_as_a_nonAtomic_operation
{
    public class Program
    {
        static int value = 1;

        public static void Main()
        {

                Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    if (value == 1)
                    {

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        value = 2;

                    }
                });

                Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    value = 3;

                });

                Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
                Console.WriteLine(value); //Displays 2

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the above non-atomic  operation into an atomic one making use of :

```
Interlocked.CompareExhange(ref value, newValue, compareTo);
```

which I have written as

```
 Interlocked.CompareExhange(ref value, value, value); //This doesn't look right!
```

and

```
Interlocked.CompareExhange(ref value, t2, t1); //will not compile
```

Questions

1. With or without Interlocked.CompareExchange value is output as 2? Why?
2. What is the correct way to reference t1, t2?
3. Why can't I reference the output of the task directly? (value, t2, t1)
4. Is some sort of conversion required or even necessary?
5. As I understand the value should be updated to 2 (value = 1) then updated to 3 instead of the current output (value = 1, updates to 3 then updates it to 2) once `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With or without Interlocked.CompareExchange value is output as 2? Why?

The real answer is: *coincidence*. Your code is non-deterministic and its behavior depends on the OS thread scheduler.

But... it's actually not surprising at all that `t1` starts its execution before `t2`. In this case, the `if (value == 1)` check is made before `t2` gets a chance to execute `value = 3;`.

To sum up, the *most probable* timeline is:

- `t1`: `value` is checked against `1`
- `t1`: `t1` goes to sleep for one second
- `t2`: `value` is set to 3
- `t1`: wakes up a second later
- `t1`: `value` is set to 2

But as I've said above, this is just what happens in practice, but tour code is *still* nondeterministic, as `t2` *could* in principle start its execution before `t1`.

> What is the correct way to reference t1, t2?

The way you do it seems about right, if I understand your question correctly.

> Why can't I reference the output of the task directly? (value, t2, t1)

You start `void` tasks, which don't *have* an output in the first place. They're represented by the `Task` type.

You may start a task which returns a result like this:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => {
    // do anything
    return 42;
});
```

In this case, `t` will be of type `Task<int>` and you'll be able to access its `Result` property when the task ends (if you try to access i before the task completes, it'll block until the task ends).

> Is some sort of conversion required or even necessary?

I'm not sure I understand your question here.

> As I understand the value should be updated to 2 (value =1) then updated to 3 instead of the current output (value =1, updates to 3 then updates it to 2) once Interlocked.CompareExchange is used?

Pretty much, yes. `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is *atomic*. It will perform the comparison *and* set the value in one step at the hardware level:

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1);
```

This is the *atomic* equivalent of:

```
if (value == 1)
    value = 2;
```

And if you do this, the final value will *always* be `3`. Because two different scenarios are possible (it's easy because now both tasks contain a single atomic statement):

- `t1` executes before `t2`:

  - `t1`: `value` is checked against `1`, which is true, so `value` is set to `2`
  - `t2`: `value` is set to 3
- `t2` executes before `t1`:

  - `t2`: `value` is set to 3
  - `t1`: `value` is checked against `1`, which is false, so `value` is left unchanged

As you can see, you'll end up with `3` in both cases.